# wkhtmltopdf - 300 dpi and cmyk color model

Tags: latex, wkhtmltopdf, dpi, cmyk

Is it possible to use wkhtmltopdf to generate a print quality pdf?

The printer's constraints require the doc to be 300 dpi and CMYK color model.  I don't see an option in wk for CMYK, and the --dpi flag seems to have no effect.

I wonder if I'm barking up the wrong tree since webkit is inherently limited?  Maybe using LaTex or something is a more robust approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes --dpi flag simply doesn't work as expected.
But there is workaround.
You can set zero-margins to make html be fitted to all page area:

wkhtmltopdf.exe -T 0 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0

This way you can set html to have width in pixels corresponds to 300 dpi.
Please note that dpi has sense for embedded images.
It seems CMYK color is not supported.

I have wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (i also tested some old versions).

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  When you say "dpi has sense for embedded images" do you mean that I should continue to specify the --dpi flag so as to ensure that the images come out at 300 dpi?  Or that wk will respect the source resolution of the images and nothing more is required on my part for those?

Comment: yes, need to specify --dpi ... there is also --image-dpi flag wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt ... while for cmyk converting please try to check imagemagick